# Lerna, what's the opposite of 'yarn run lerna add component-a'

Tags: yarnpkg, lerna

With Lerna to add a package to all other package file I can use - 
`yarn run lerna add component-a`

With this I see the item added to all package files in my overall repo.

If I use
`yarn run lerna clean component-a`

the output suggests its remove the component from the node_modules but it still exists inside the package files that were added via the `add` command.

So what will reverse the `add` command fully.

Comment: From what I've read on other pages, I do not think there is an opposite or a simple reversal of the above command.
Once its in every package file, then you have to remove each one individually. Then after that run lerna bootstrap.

Still do not know enough to be sure, as in if I just remove (uninstall) each package what is left behind, why run lerna bootstrap?